# join columns from two table into one

Tags: postgresql

I have table AnalysisForm

```
a_id| a_description | medical_card_id
-------------------------
 1  | Analysis1    | 5
 2  | Analysis2    | 3
 3  | Analysis3    | 2
 4  | Analysis4    | 1
```

and table DicomForm

```
d_id| d_description | medical_card_id
-------------------------
 1  | DicomForm1   | 5
 2  | DicomForm2   | 3
 3  | DicomForm3   | 2
 4  | DicomForm4   | 1
```

Now I want to get info by medical_card_id = 5 like this

```
form_id| form_description | medical_card_id
-------------------------
 1     | DicomForm1       | 5
 1     | Analysis1        | 5
```

How can I make it in Postgres?

Comment: This looks more like a `UNION` not a join

Comment: My example is very simplified, but yeah, now I understand how can I resolve my original task, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that you want a *union* query here, rather than a join:

```
SELECT a_id AS form_id, a_description AS form_description, medical_card_id
FROM AnalysisForm
WHERE medical_card_id = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT d_id, d_description, medical_card_id
FROM DicomForm
WHERE medical_card_id = 5;
```